Issue displaying SVG images with coil in Jetpack Compose: Invalid color keyword (display-p3) error


I'm using Coil with Jetpack Compose to load SVG images in my app, but I'm encountering an issue where some images load correctly, while others do not. Upon inspecting the logs, I see an error related to an invalid color keyword: color(display-p3 ...). The images that fail to load have this issue.
Here's the relevant code I’m using to load the images:
@Composable
fun coilPainter(
    imageUrl: Any?,
    scale: Scale = Scale.FIT,
    size: Size = Size.ORIGINAL,
): AsyncImagePainter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory()) // Using SvgDecoder for SVG support
        .crossfade(true)
        .size(size)
        .scale(scale)
        .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .build(),
)

@Composable
fun ImageProfileLoader(
    image: Any? = null,
    text: String? = null,
    isDefaultBankIcon: Boolean = false,
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.Gray,
    size: Dp = 55.dp,
    fontSize: Dp = 16.dp,
) {
    val painter = coilPainter(imageUrl = image)

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(size)
            .background(backgroundColor, shape = CircleShape)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
            if (text?.isEmpty() == true) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.default_image_profile).takeIf { !isDefaultBankIcon } ?: painterResource(R.drawable.default_bank_icon),
                    contentDescription = "",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
            } else {
                TextCustom(
                    text = text?.first()?.uppercaseChar().toString(),
                    fontSize = fontSize,
                    color = Color171717
                )
            }
        }

        if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }

        if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(size)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .shimmerEffect()
            )
        }
    }
}


Here is error I got

Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.6980 0.9137)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.5922 0.8392)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.5725 0.8275)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.4980 0.7686)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.4392 0.7294)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.4078 0.7059)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.4000 0.7020)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.0000 0.4000 0.7020)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.9490 0.8941 0.8039)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.8745 0.7294 0.5020)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.8275 0.6275 0.3098)
Invalid colour keyword: color(display-p3 0.8118 0.5882 0.2392)```


Please include some explanation of what your code is doing and what you're having trouble with.  Without any context, it's difficult to know what exactly you're having issues with.

This seems to be related to the SVG parser. Please [edit] the question and add the content of one of the problematic SVG files so we can investigate further. Please also specify the Coil version you use.

This issue is caused by the SVG containing color_p3. Those colours are supported on iOS only and Android is not supported.
